# Avoid importig React and ReactDOM using typescript declaration files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I know that there are some info concerning this question.
I want create many react components easily without importing `React` into every `*.tsx` file.

May be there is a better way to achieve this but i know only one solution: 
Using `*.d.ts` files

I have typescript pet project. Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ]
    }
}
```

And here's global.d.ts file that i placed under `src` directory

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts"/>

declare const React: typeof React
declare const ReactDOM: typeof ReactDOM
```

It works fine, but i believe there is better way.

`React` is a namespace, can i export this into my `global.d.ts` file, without declaring it as `const`?

---

I tried with `include` option in `tsconfig.json`. it works, but VSCode doesn't helps, it can't see types listed in tsconfig.json file

I believe i don't understand how to write d.ts files properly, can you help me with it?

**UPDATE**

i don't want to import `React` because it's available globally

```
<script src="/static/node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="/static/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**
I've found this way:

```
import * as react from "react"
import * as react_dom from "react-dom"
import * as reactstrap from "reactstrap"

declare global {
    type React = typeof react
    type ReactDOM = typeof react_dom
    namespace Reactstrap {
        class Nav extends reactstrap.Nav {}
        class NavItem extends reactstrap.NavItem {}
        class NavLink<T> extends reactstrap.NavLink<T> {}
        class Alert extends reactstrap.Alert {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Just trying to understand... Why dont you want to put `import React from 'react';` in your files?

Comment: This new compiler option might be of intrest to you: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30776 (soon to be released in 3.5)

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo, updated queestion. I use es6 modules, don't want to use any js bundlers for development